# Collect stdout/stderr logs with sidecar container

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, logstash, filebeat

I use company originated cloud environment which doesn't allow us to use node log collector and asks us to use a sidecar container to ship logs to ELK. However our container prints all the logs to stdout/stderr by following the [12 factor app](https://12factor.net/logs) practice.

Is there any way to collect stdout/stderr logs using a sidecar container (Prefered to use Filebeat)? I was checking documentation but it's not clearly mentioned anywhere.

There's another way in which I print all the logs to the specific directory within app container and share the volume with the sidecar Filebeat container. However, with this approach, I should think about the log rotation as well, which introduces more complexity. (Probably I need to create another container to aggregate logs and rotate logs.)

---

I think the recommended approach could be

- container logs go stdout/stderr
- Filebeat is deployed as Daemon Set
- Use Hint Base Autodiscover

Answer (score 0):

Consider one of the below options

1. Deploy Fluentd daemonset to collect the logs from all pods from a node

OR

2. Deploy Fluent-bit daemonset to collect logs and get it forward to Fluentd pod

Configure Fluentd pod to push the logs to Elasticsearch.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Even I go for option No. 2  I need to collect the logs from a node right?

Comment: yes. logs need to be collected from all pods from each node using a daemonset.